# What is the "client-side architecture model"?

Tags: architecture

I am reading the recently released "[Field Guide to Web Applications](http://www.html5rocks.com/webappfieldguide/toc/index)" (from the Google Chrome team). The book encourages the use of the "client-side architecture model", but never really defines it, as far as I can tell. What's the gist of this model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/ClientSideArchitecture

> Google Refine's client-side is in HTML, CSS, and Javascript and uses
>   jQuery and jQuery UI.

It basically means to use HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery, AJAX efficiently in the clients browser letting their computers take load off your server and process data faster.

Comment: Hmm, that link doesn't seem very authoritative, but your synopsis makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You do realize that the link is to Google, the very people that wrote the book that you've been reading. That link is just as authoritative as The Field Guide to Web Applications.